# Local variables are empty when debugging c++ in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, qt6

I'm debugging c++ Qt6 code in code-insiders and local variable are empty. This does not apply to int and boolean, but to more complex local variables like QString. Member variables display properly. I just tried eclipse CDT and it shows all variables properly.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/gitStatus",
            "args": ["--verbose"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: The debugger needs to find the debug information for QString as well. I think that's in the heart of this issue.

Comment: I now believe this is a Qt problem. When I have a local variable like std::string s{"Fred"}; vscode displays it properly. With a local variable like QString s1{"Fred"}, however, vscode shows it as empty.

Comment: It is unlikely that you have Qt compiled in debug mode or have debug symbols shipped. There is also the issue of debug format in the executable versus the debugger version you are using.

Comment: I had removed QT_NO_DEBUG and compiled with c++ -g -O0

Comment: Also, eclipse CDT displays all variables while vscode can't display Qt6 local variables. So I think that vscode has a problem with Qt.

Comment: If you are compiling with clang and debugging with gdb it is possible that the debugger does not recognize the new debug formats in the executable.

Comment: I'm compiling with gcc: (g++ -g -O0 ... ) and debugging with gdb

Comment: I would recommend to ditch visual studio code and start gdb manually.